# why $\sin(x)$ is maximized if $x = 2n\pi+ \pi/2$

Tags: trigonometry

I was working on a homework assignment and a friend told me that $7.06\sin(30x)$ will be maximum when $30x = 2n\pi + \pi/2$, can someone explain?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  As for the question in the title, what is the maximum value of $\sin x$?  For which $x$ value does it occur in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$?  What is the period of the sine function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for $f(x)=7.06 \sin(30x)$, the maximum is when $f'(x)=0$, where:

$$f'(x)=7.06\cdot 30 \cos(30x)\tag{1}$$

Set $(1)$ to zero, and you get:
$$\cos(30x)=0\implies 30x=\frac\pi2$$
And $\cos(2n\pi+x)=\cos x$, meaning the complete solution should be:

$$30x=2n\pi+\frac\pi2\,\, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1):

The values of $\sin \theta$ are always between $-1$ and $1$, with $1$ occurring whenever $\theta$ is $90^{\circ}$ or any other angle coterminal with $90^\circ$ (for example, $450^\circ$ or $810^\circ$ or $-270^\circ$ or any other value you can get by adding or subtracting a multiple of $360^\circ$).  We can summarize this by saying that the maximum value of $\sin \theta$ occurs when
$$\theta = 90^\circ \pm 360n^\circ$$

If we translate this into radians, the maximum occurs when
$$\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} \pm 2\pi n$$
Now you asked about the function $f(x)=7.06\sin(30x)$.   This function has values that are always between $-7.06$ and $7.06$, with the maximum occurring precisely when $\sin(30x) = 1$.  But this is exactly the same question just solved, with $\theta = 30x$.  So we need
$$30x = \frac{\pi}{2} \pm 2\pi n$$
which is what your friend told you.